# Lualatex does not see authors of a document

Tags: luatex, amsart

I want to override the `\maketitle` command, but I get a warning that no `\author` is given.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\title{test}
\author{Aleksandr Kozlovskiy}
\date{\today}
\thanks{This document  was printted in LaTex by Aleksandr Kozlovskiy from minsk.}
\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{
\textbf{\@title}
\textit{\@author}
\text{\@thanks}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle
this is a test document
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

AMS classes store the author (and thanks) in a different macro:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\title{test}
\author{Aleksandr Kozlovskiy}
\date{\today}
\thanks{This document  was printted in LaTex by Aleksandr Kozlovskiy from minsk.}
\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{
\textbf{\@title}
\textit{\authors}
\def\thanks##1{##1\par}
\text{\thankses}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle
this is a test document
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very mutch for your help,but it very interesting for me,why in several examples to override \maketitle people use \@author command?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy the standard article, report, book, classes uses `\@author` but it is not a documented interface that is just the internal macro those classes use, and ams classes set up the frontmatter differently.